# Using latest version of emacs

Tags: software-installation

I have installed an instance of emacs

using

`make install`

But how can I then run it.  There is a link

```
ls -lrt /usr/local/bin/emacs

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        13 Sep  9  2022 emacs -> emacs-29.0.50
```

but this is to the old one, I have installed `emacs-30.0.50` which is located here

```
~/Opstk/bld/emacs/emacs-30.0.50/src/emacs-30.0.50.1
```

Comment: Does running the command `~/Opstk/bld/emacs/emacs-30.0.50/src/emacs-30.0.50.1` work?  If not, what is the output?  If it does work, I think it would be as simple as changing the symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/emacs` to point to the new version

Comment: It works.  But I now want the new version as the one I use in terminal,

Comment: What would be the symbolic link command ?

Comment: `sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/emacs; sudo ln -s ~/Opstk/bld/emacs/emacs-30.0.50/src/emacs-30.0.50.1 /usr/local/bin/emacs`

Comment: Right, because I could not make the link as it already existed.